# Does Maven Mojo have Equivalent to ant's DirSet?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-mojo

I'm uplifting an ant plugin to maven plugin and my ant plugin used a [DirSet](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/tools/ant/types/DirSet.html) and I see that maven only has a [FileSet](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.1/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/FileSet.html).

- Can I use FileSet to just gather directories?
- Should I create my own dirset class either from reviewing Ant's PatternSet - DirSet code and then implementing a similar solution using maven's PatternSet and or FileSet?
- Is there a better way to gather directories with includes and excludes?

Thanks for the help

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Found it on [Maven's File Management examples](http://maven.apache.org/shared/file-management/examples/mojo.html) page.

```
FileSetManager fileSetManager = new FileSetManager();
String[] includedFiles = fileSetManager.getIncludedFiles( fileset );
String[] includedDir = fileSetManager.getIncludedDirectories( fileset );
String[] excludedFiles = fileSetManager.getExcludedFiles( fileset );
String[] excludedDir = fileSetManager.getExcludedDirectories( fileset );
fileSetManager.delete( fileset );
```